# Spring RestTemplate: Request/response json not getting logged

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, slf4j

I am having a Spring boot application and using RestTemplate for my REST API. Logger is slf4j. My problem is I am not able to logs the json request/response.

My application.yml configuration:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web.client: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate: DEBUG
    com.rbc.myadvisor.advisor.manager.rest: DEBUG
    org.hibernate: ERROR
    org.apache.http: DEBUG
    org.apache.http.wire: DEBUG
```

With this configuration, I was expecting logs to having request/response json but somehow that logs are not getting printed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to simply set org.springframework to debug and perform your Operation.

Though your log size will increase and it will be more verbose you are sure to find in log.

After finding log entry check the package name ,then revert back the initial change and add the new package in application.yml. this way you will get request and response logged and your log file won't grow.

If above way won't work change from debug to trace

Comment: The logs are getting printed but the issue is it is not in json format. It gives you the value but the key is missing. Currently it is being printed as [[1,name]], what I am looking for [["id":1,"firstName": "name"]]